# Circular lists in C#

Tags: c#

I am not very experienced with C#. I am trying to build circular lists and I have done it like this:

```
public List<string> items = new List<string> {"one", "two", "three"};
private int index = 0;

void nextItem() {
    if (index < items.Count - 1)
        index += 1;
    else
        index = 0;

    setItem();
}

void previousItem() {
    if (index > 0)
        index -= 1;
    else
        index = items.Count - 1;

    setItem();
}

void Update() {
         if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow)) nextItem();
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow))  previousItem();
}
```

But now I am wondering: Am I reinventing the wheel? Does C# already come with a proper data structure for this?

EDIT: In case some context is needed. I have a game menu, where I display a collection of items, and I want that when I press "next" and Im at the last one, to show the first item again.

Comment: Your list isn't circular, just the methods that index it. Are you just trying to index through a list that wraps around, or do you really want a circular buffer?

Comment: using queue is much better here.

Comment: I have a game, where I display a list of items in a menu. When I reach the last, I want to show the first item again.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Really? A data structure that only supports adding at one end and removing at the other is much better for `previousItem`?

Comment: Already asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518395/creating-a-very-simple-singly-circular-list-c-sharp

Comment: I think this approach is fine. the important thing is you have a flag of which item is currently selected (which you do), so what else are you hoping for?

Comment: @musefan: I was wondering if there was some sort of Data Structure that had some sort of `.current` attribute, and when I did `.next()` maybe it looped the current element through it.

Comment: does indexes matter here? or you just want to move over items one by one? i mean for example you dont want to go from 1 to 10 right?

Comment: Well, the movement can go in both direction, as seen in the Update() function...

Comment: You can simplify the calculation of the next index to `index = (index+1)%items.Count;`. Similarly, the calculation of the previous index can be simplified to `index = (items.Count+index-1)%items.Count;` (although perhaps "simplify" is a relative term in this context...)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a very simple Singly Circular List C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518395/creating-a-very-simple-singly-circular-list-c-sharp)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With utilization of the [`%` (remainder) operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx) your code gets quite simple:

```
void nextItem() {
    index++; // increment index
    index %= items.Count; // clip index (turns to 0 if index == items.Count)
    // as a one-liner:
    /* index = (index + 1) % items.Count; */

    setItem();
}

void previousItem() {
    index--; // decrement index
    if(index < 0) {
        index = items.Count - 1; // clip index (sadly, % cannot be used here, because it is NOT a modulus operator)
    }
    // or above code as a one-liner:
    /* index = (items.Count+index-1)%items.Count; */ // (credits to Matthew Watson)

    setItem();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also write your own circular list

```
public class CircularList<T> : List<T>, IEnumerable<T>
{
    public new IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new CircularEnumerator<T>(this);
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new CircularEnumerator<T>(this);
    }
}

class CircularEnumerator<T> : IEnumerator<T>
{
    private readonly List<T> list;
    int i = 0;

    public CircularEnumerator(List<T> list){
        this.list = list;
    }

    public T Current => list[i];

    object IEnumerator.Current => this;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        i = (i + 1) % list.Count;
        return true;
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        i = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why does CircularList need to implement IEnumerable?

Comment: Right, it is not necessarry, but it must overwrite the enumerator capabilities of the List class to achieve the circular behaviour - in my mind, implementing IEnumerable makes this more clear

Comment: So if you throw it into a foreach loop or other IEnumerable loop, it enumerates infinitely? That's both kind of cool and deviously annoying. Needs something like lap detection or number of laps cutoff threshold as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

```
    public class CircularList<T> : List<T>
    {
        private int Index;

        public CircularList() : this(0) { }

        public CircularList(int index)
        {
            if (index < 0 || index >= Count)
                throw new Exception(string.Format("Index must between {0} and {1}", 0, Count));

            Index = index;
        }

        public T Current()
        {
            return this[Index];
        }

        public T Next()
        {
            Index++;
            Index %= Count;

            return this[Index];
        }

        public T Previous()
        {
            Index--;
            if (Index < 0)
                Index = Count - 1;

            return this[Index];
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            Index = 0;
        }

        public void MoveToEnd()
        {
            Index = Count - 1;
        }

    }
```